# how to set "data-value" Attribute of div in angular 2

Tags: templates, angular

```
<div data-value="{{tagName}}">{{tagName}}</div>
```

Getting "data-value is not a valid attribute" of div error.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

By default Angular2 binds to properties for performance reasons. To explicitly bind to attributes use one of these options

```
attr.data-value="{{tagName}}"
```

or

```
[attr.data-value]="tagName"
```

Comment: It´s works perfectly. Thanks a lot.